# Tensorflow inference run time high on first data point, decreases on subsequent data points

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api, pre-trained-model

I am running inference using one of the models from TensorFlow's object detection module. I'm looping over my test images in the same session and doing sess.run(). However, on profiling these runs, I realize the first run always has a higher time as compared to the subsequent runs.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063489/first-tf-session-run-performs-dramatically-different-from-later-runs-why), as to why that happens, but there was no solution on how to fix.

I'm deploying the object detection inference pipeline on an Intel i7 CPU. The time for one session.run(), for 1,2,3, and the 4th image looks something like (in seconds):

```
1. 84.7132628
2. 1.495621681
3. 1.505012751
4. 1.501652718
```

Just a background on what all I have tried:

- I tried using the TFRecords approach TensorFlow gave as a sample [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/oid_inference_and_evaluation.md). I hoped it would work better because it doesn't use a feed_dict. But since more I/O operations are involved, I'm not sure it'll be ideal. I tried making it work without writing to the disk, but always got some error regarding the encoding of the image.
- I tried using the TensorFlow datasets to feed the data, but I wasn't sure how to provide the input, since the during inference I need to provide input for "image tensor" key in the graph. Any ideas on how to use this to provide input to a frozen graph?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

TLDR: Looking to reduce the run time of inference for the first image - for deployment purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have seen that the first inference takes longer, the difference (84 Vs 1.5) that is shown there seems to be a bit unbelievable. Are you counting the time to load model also, inside this time metric? Can this could be the difference for the large time difference? Is the topology that complex, so that this time difference could be justified?

My suggestions:

1. Try Openvino : See if the topology you are working on, is supported in Openvino. OpenVino is known to speed up the inference workloads by a substantial amount due to it's capability to optimize network operations. Also, the time taken to load openvino model, is comparitively lower in most of the cases.
2. Regarding the TFRecords Approach, could you please share the exact error and at what stage you got the error?
3. Regarding Tensorflow datasets, could you please check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23523 & https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets. Regarding the "image tensor" key in the graph, I hope, your original inference pipeline should give you some clues.