# Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED , Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cudnn

I've tried using Tensorflow GPU accelerator in google colab with local runtime on my machine which has the following system information

- OS Platform and Distribution : Windows 10
- TensorFlow version: 2.1
- Python version: 3.6.10
- CUDA/cuDNN version: Cudnn - 7.5.6 , CUDA- 10.1
- GPU: Nividia Geforce RTX 2060

I've followed all the steps precisely on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu and ran then ran this code to check if it can discover my gpu and to see the difference in speed between it and cpu:

```
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
import timeit

device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  print(
      '\n\nThis error most likely means that this notebook is not '
      'configured to use a GPU.  Change this in Notebook Settings via the '
      'command palette (cmd/ctrl-shift-P) or the Edit menu.\n\n')
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')

def cpu():
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    random_image_cpu = tf.random.normal((100, 100, 100, 3))
    net_cpu = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 7)(random_image_cpu)
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(net_cpu)

def gpu():
  with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    random_image_gpu = tf.random.normal((100, 100, 100, 3))
    net_gpu = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 7)(random_image_gpu)
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(net_gpu)
  
# We run each op once to warm up; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067900
cpu()
gpu()

# Run the op several times.
print('Time (s) to convolve 32x7x7x3 filter over random 100x100x100x3 images '
      '(batch x height x width x channel). Sum of ten runs.')
print('CPU (s):')
cpu_time = timeit.timeit('cpu()', number=10, setup="from __main__ import cpu")
print(cpu_time)
print('GPU (s):')
gpu_time = timeit.timeit('gpu()', number=10, setup="from __main__ import gpu")
print(gpu_time)
print('GPU speedup over CPU: {}x'.format(int(cpu_time/gpu_time)))
```

it returned the following error:

```
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-121519b30cf2> in <module>
     29 # We run each op once to warm up; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067900
     30 cpu()
---> 31 gpu()
     32 
     33 # Run the op several times.

<ipython-input-1-121519b30cf2> in gpu()
     24   with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
     25     random_image_gpu = tf.random.normal((100, 100, 100, 3))
---> 26     net_gpu = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 7)(random_image_gpu)
     27     return tf.math.reduce_sum(net_gpu)
     28 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    820           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    821               self._compute_dtype):
--> 822             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    823           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    824           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
    207       inputs = array_ops.pad(inputs, self._compute_causal_padding())
    208 
--> 209     outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    210 
    211     if self.use_bias:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py in __call__(self, inp, filter)
   1133           call_from_convolution=False)
   1134     else:
-> 1135       return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
   1136     # copybara:strip_end
   1137     # copybara:insert return self.conv_op(inp, filter)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py in __call__(self, inp, filter)
    638 
    639   def __call__(self, inp, filter):  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
--> 640     return self.call(inp, filter)
    641 
    642 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py in __call__(self, inp, filter)
    237         padding=self.padding,
    238         data_format=self.data_format,
--> 239         name=self.name)
    240 
    241 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, data_format, dilations, name, filters)
   2009                            data_format=data_format,
   2010                            dilations=dilations,
-> 2011                            name=name)
   2012 
   2013 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, explicit_paddings, data_format, dilations, name)
    931             input, filter, strides=strides, use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu,
    932             padding=padding, explicit_paddings=explicit_paddings,
--> 933             data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
    934       except _core._SymbolicException:
    935         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py in conv2d_eager_fallback(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, explicit_paddings, data_format, dilations, name, ctx)
   1020   explicit_paddings, "data_format", data_format, "dilations", dilations)
   1021   _result = _execute.execute(b"Conv2D", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs,
-> 1022                              ctx=ctx, name=name)
   1023   if _execute.must_record_gradient():
   1024     _execute.record_gradient(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]
```

and this is the log from the jupyter terminal:

```
2020-08-09 04:37:22.168805: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:24.322956: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-08-09 04:37:24.329330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.599803: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.335GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2020-08-09 04:37:25.607874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.616921: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.626584: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.635135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.650044: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.659390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.681098: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:25.686397: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.217444: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-09 04:37:26.222044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.225124: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
2020-08-09 04:37:26.228586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 4604 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-08-09 04:37:26.239786: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.335GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2020-08-09 04:37:26.249100: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.254350: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.260971: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.265307: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.271569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.276251: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.281798: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.287682: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.291846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-09 04:37:26.298235: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.300794: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
2020-08-09 04:37:26.305262: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 4604 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-08-09 04:37:26.313775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.335GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2020-08-09 04:37:26.328318: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.339994: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.345874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.352587: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.359694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.365286: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.371099: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.375749: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.380113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.335GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2020-08-09 04:37:26.393424: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.403150: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.408577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.423141: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.428838: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.434061: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.438479: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:26.443288: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.446511: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-09 04:37:26.453204: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2020-08-09 04:37:26.458931: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
2020-08-09 04:37:26.463016: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4604 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-08-09 04:37:26.823644: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-09 04:37:27.877441: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-08-09 04:37:27.882143: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
```

I've tried the solutions mentioned here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/could-not-create-cudnn-handle-cudnn-status-alloc-failed/108261/2 but to no avail, I hope I can someone who can assist me in this here.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? If not, can you please execute the code in the link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices and check if GPU is visible to Tensorflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` returns `device_type='GPU'` means, there was no issue with TF_GPU installation.

So, in the next step you can try GPU memory resources management by allowing GPU memory growth.

It can be done by calling `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`, which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory as needed for the runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as the program gets run and more GPU memory is needed, we extend the GPU memory region allocated to the TensorFlow process.

To turn on memory growth for a specific GPU, use the following code prior to allocating any tensors or executing any ops.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

For more details please refer [TensorFlow GPU Guide.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)