# Maximum 1X speedup achieved on Macbook Pro 2019 GPU for tensorflow operations

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

**Context:**

I wanted to test the speedup that we can achieve by using Macbook Pro 2019 GPU for `tensorflow` operations.

As advised, in the following snippet, I am using `tensorflow` library's in-built function `tf.multiply()` to fetch the output of multiplication operation of a tensor with a constant:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2],
                      [3, 4]])

def cpu():
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        tensor_1 = tf.multiply(tensor, 2)
        return tensor_1

def gpu():
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
        tensor_1 = tf.multiply(tensor, 2)
        return tensor_1


# We run each op once to warm up; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067900
cpu()
gpu()

import time
n = 10000

start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    cpu()
end = time.time()

cpu_time = end - start


start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    gpu()
end = time.time()
gpu_time = end - start

print('GPU speedup over CPU: {}x'.format((cpu_time / gpu_time)))
```

**Results:**

I could achieve a maximum speedup of 1X.

**My Question:**

Ideally, if the `tf.multiply()` is optimised to run on the GPU, why am I not getting a better speedup of lets say 2X to 10X?

**System & environment:**

1. MacOS Ventura 13.3.1
2. Processor - 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
3. Graphics - AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
4. Memory - 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
5. `tensorflow-macos` python package version = 2.9.0
6. `tensorflow-metal` python package version = 0.6.0
7. Python version - 3.8.16

Comment: perhaps you might try it with a `tensor` that is 2 or 3 orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: This computation is ridiculously small to be accelerated by a GPU.

Comment: Thanks folks. Cited you in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Special thanks to @JonSG and Dr. Matias Valdenegro-Toro (@Dr. Snoopy) for their comments to try with the operations involving tensors of the higher orders (or shape).

I implemented the tensor multiplication as follows and could achieve 8X speedup:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor_1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=(400, 2700))
tensor_2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2700, 800))

def cpu():
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        tensor_3 = tf.matmul(tensor_1, tensor_2)
        return tensor_3

def gpu():
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
        tensor_3 = tf.matmul(tensor_1, tensor_2)
        return tensor_3


# We run each op once to warm up; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067900
cpu()
gpu()

import time
n = 1000

start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    cpu()
end = time.time()

cpu_time = end - start


start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    gpu()
end = time.time()
gpu_time = end - start

print('GPU speedup over CPU: {}x'.format((cpu_time / gpu_time)))
```

**Output:**

```
GPU speedup over CPU: 8.871644178654558x
```